# Proof for determinants of Matrices and Their Transposes

Tags: matrices, determinant

Prove or disprove that for any square matrix $A$, $\det(AA^T )= \det(A^TA)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What do you know about the determinant of $A^T$?..

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322064/determinants-and-matrices

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

We have

$$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$$